# VS Code Extension: How to make my extension load npm package from user workspace rather the bundled with my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a custom VS Code extension to some stuff. Basically, I'm relying on a few npm packages to get the job done.

But I would to like to do something like `vscode-eslint` extension does: if user have `eslint` package installed, it will use the local package instead the bundled one.

Basically I want to do this behavior:

[image]

Would this be possible with VSCode?

PS: I tried to study vscode eslint extension, but I was not able to understand how it handles this situation.

Comment: maybe run require(...) and specify the name of the package or path to it?

Comment: Does this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions/10) seem relatable?